# Groupby 3 column values and find the 3rd column count in descending order and sum up the count values by ignoring the first count value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a groupby for 3 column values and wanted to find the below from a python dataframe:
1. 3rd column value counts in descending order
2. sum up the count values by ignoring the first count value

I have tried with the below 2 lines of code, but not getting the desired results, can anyone help me out in this! Thanks in advance!

```
df.groupby(['Gender', 'Area Code', 'Population'])["Population"].count()

df.groupby(['Gender', 'Area Code', 'Population'])["Population"].count().reset_index(name='count').sort_values(['count'], ascending=False)
```

**df:**

```
 Gender Area Code   Population
Male    RJ12    650
Male    RJ12    650
Male    RJ12    200
Male    DL25    230
Male    DL25    230
Male    MH02    550
Male    MH02    230
Male    MH02    550
Male    MH02    550
Male    MH02    740
Female  DL25    230
Female  DL25    430
Female  RJ07    850
Female  RJ07    950
Female  RJ07    950
Female  RJ07    450
Female  RJ07    950
Female  RJ07    450
```

**Expected Result 1:**

[image]

**Expected Result 2:** ***(Ignoring the first value of count highlighted in brown color in the above image)***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
out1 = (
    df.groupby(["Gender", "Area Code", "Population"], sort=False)
    .size()
    .to_frame(name="Count")
)

out2 = out1.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(
    lambda x: x["Count"].sort_values(ascending=False)[1:].sum()
)

print(out1.reset_index())
print(out2.reset_index(name="Sum"))
```

Prints:

```
    Gender Area Code  Population  Count
0     Male      RJ12         650      2
1     Male      RJ12         200      1
2     Male      DL25         230      2
3     Male      MH02         550      3
4     Male      MH02         230      1
5     Male      MH02         740      1
6   Female      DL25         230      1
7   Female      DL25         430      1
8   Female      RJ07         850      1
9   Female      RJ07         950      3
10  Female      RJ07         450      2

   Gender Area Code  Sum
0  Female      DL25    1
1  Female      RJ07    3
2    Male      DL25    0
3    Male      MH02    2
4    Male      RJ12    1
```